# Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE error perl

Tags: perl, syntax-error

I can't fix this error...

```
@temp=split(/(/)/,$headerLine);
```

this error appears

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/( <-- HERE
```

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
@temp=split(/(\/)/,$headerLine);
```

or

```
@temp=split(m&(/)&,$headerLine);
```

The slash in the parentheses prematurely terminates your regular expression.

Comment: Or `m{(/)}` or even m<(/)>...  Depending on what would look more readable.

Comment: I thought three proposals would be sufficient. =)

Comment: Sure, three is enough.

Answer (score 6):

Your second `/` character is terminating the regular expression, so Perl is interpreting your code as:

```
@temp=split /(/
```

followed by garbage.

Simply escape the literal `/`:

```
@temp=split(/(\/)/, $headerLine)
```